# Oracle Stored Procedure with User Defined Type in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to use a stored procedure for

```
variable data refcursor;
execute MyPkg(to_date('2010-08-11','yyyy-MM-dd'), TEXT_ARRAY('tempa','tempb'), :data);
```

Where `TEXT_ARRAY` is a udt of type `TABLE OF varchar2(255)`

C# Code Snippet:

```
        var cmd = new OracleCommand("BEGIN MyPkg(:Param1, :Param2, :Param3); END;", con);
        var param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("Param1", OracleDbType.Date);
        var param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("Param2", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        var param3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("Param3", OracleDbType.RefCursor);

        param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        param1.Value = DateTime.Now;


        param2.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;

        param2.Value = new[] { "tempa", “tempb”};
        param2.Size = 2;
        param2.ArrayBindSize = new[] { 20, 20 };

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And am getting error:

> An exception of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException'
>   occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user
>   code Additional information: External component has thrown an
>   exception. -- ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: **wrong number
>   or types of arguments in call to 'MyPkg**‘\nORA-06550: line 1, column
>   7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"

Any clues on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OracleDbType.Array instead of varchar2 for param2.

Comment: I get error - OracleDbType does not contain definition for Array (Am using version 12.1.24160719)

Comment: I am referring Oracle.DataAccess.Client(v2.112.1.0). Which version you are using?

Comment: Am using Oracle.DataAccess.Client(v4.112.1.0)